# Using multiple sensors on ESP8266 Wifi module

Tags: sensors, esp8266

I have an ESP8266 ESP-01 WiFi module.
I have a project where I need to use the following and send their data to a firebase database.

2x Force Sensitive Resistors(Sensor)

1x GPS module

My question is what GPS module can I use to send GPS location thru the ESP8266 Wifi module. My ESP-01 has only 2 GPIO. What should I do so I can use 2 FSR and GPS module at the same time send all 3 data to firebase realtime database.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would go for an i2c A/D converter, example ADS1015 (4 analog input, 12 bit) and connect that to the ESP-01.

Ref.:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6IAkYpmA1DQ&t=32s

Comment: Hello thank you for response. I searched this device and does this work like a 'GPIO' extension? Since ESP-01 only have 2 if I use this it will have 4 inputs? What is the connection when I use it on ESP-01?
 http://www.esp8266learning.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/wemos-ads1015_bb.png

Comment: It has 4 GPIO, https://acrobotic.com/media/wysiwyg/products/esp8266_esp01_horizontal-01.png . And yes ADS1015 uses a i2c communication, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C, an universal serial buss where you can connect several devices to.

Comment: If I will use a different esp version NodeMCU V3 ESP8266 ESP-12E will it give me more GPIO slots? I checked them and found out that the ADS1015 price is closer to a new esp. What do you think? I just need enough slots for 2 FRS and 1 GPS module. Thanks

Comment: The ESP8266 chip only have one ADC (Analog input). And yes it will give you more I/O pins. So its the demand for two FRS that causes the demand for an alternative.

Comment: The ADC analog input is for the FRS or the GPS? Sorry Im really lost right now. Im trying to use this https://imgur.com/Rk67hI1 Will this be enough to power 2 FRS and a gps module? Thank you for your patience...

Comment: ADC = Analog to Digital Converter = Analog input that can measure voltage. And I assume that the FRS is analog resistors? Oh and the NodeMCU is nice, I prefer WEMOS D1, but it's quite the same

Comment: I think the NodeMCU got 1ADC and WEMOS got 11 Digital I/O pins
1 Analog Input pin which I think not enough for 2 FRS which uses ADC pins what do you suggest?

Comment: If I'm going to help you, you have to work also, not just asking! And I can't see that you give credits. So google the words "ESP8266 ADS1015 arduino"

Comment: I apologize. I guess I got too dependent on your replies and haven't done my part but thank you for still replying even though im kinda annoying. I have decided to use an Arduino UNO r3 which have 5 ADC slots and gonna use the Esp8266 esp-01 to send the data to firebase. Thank you for helping.

Comment: @Snoopy You are welcome and if you need any help in the future you are welcome, and the choice you have made is a good one. And one thing that also drive one to answer is to get credit for it :-) its the arrows to the left of the discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You really need something external to both provide the analog inputs for the force sensors and the serial communication for the GPS module.

The simplest "something" is another microcontroller.  Ideally one with two UART ports.

You can then:

- Communicate between the microcontroller and the GPS with one UART
- Sample the FSRs with the microcontroller
- Format and send the data to the ESP-01 through the other UART

Using `SoftwareSerial` you chould just about do it with an Arduino Uno (though you'd have to disconnect whatever was on the hardware UART every time you wanted to program it), but ideally something with more UARTs would be better, such as a Mega2560.

A halfway house between the two would be a board based around the ATMega32U2 which uses a direct USB connection for programming leaving the hardware UART free to be used permanently. However you'd still need to use `SoftwareSerial` to emulate the second UART (maybe best for the GPS since it's then only used for receiving).

Comment: Why not just write the sensor-handling code on the ESP8266, using an external ADC to work around the single-ADC on the ESP8266? The ESP is quite capable.

Comment: @josecanuc The chip is capable, but the ESP-01 is seriously lacking in IO pins. It has the UART pins and two GPIOs that are used to select the boot mode, so you have to be very careful with them. Best to stick to UART only.

Comment: @Majenko Thanks for the response I am still new to embedded systems and somehow i cannot understand some of it but I have an USB to TTL UART and Arduino UNO to use. My code is currently programmed in the wifi module using the GPIO2 as the sensor #1. i do not know where to plug the sensor#2 and gps module. If I plug them at the arduino or UART how will they send data since the code is inside the wifi module. I am confused Sorry im beginner

Comment: @Majenko If I will use an NodeMCU V3 ESP8266 ESP-12E instead will it be enough to run all 2sensors and 1 gps module?

Comment: Unless it has an added external ADC chip you still only get 1 ADC channel. However it is possible to add an external ADC chip to it for more channels. The GPS should be able to attach directly.

Comment: Thanks! May I know the difference between the ADC slot and GPIO slot? So I need 2 ADC slots for the FRS and the GPS will attach to the GPIO? This is the exact product im trying to buy https://imgur.com/Rk67hI1

Comment: FSRs are analog. You need to connect them to an analog (ADC) port. The GSM is UART. You need to connect it to a pair of UART pins or a pair of GPIO pins which you emulate UART on with SoftwareSerial.

Comment: I understand now thank you. Last question what ESP8266 can you suggest that has atleast 2 ADC pins for FSR and some GPIO for the GPS? There are so many too choose from and i dont know what to use best.

Comment: No ESP8266 has more than one ADC pin. You may find a board with an external ADC chip added but I don't know of one of hand. Wemos and NodeMCU are probably the boards to look at.